# ¿Es posible generar consecutivos basados en el cambio de una columnas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo este caso:
Me interesa en SQL Server 2008, poder asignar un consecutivo a los registros pero que este se resetee a 1 cada vez que cambia una fecha en la consulta.

Por ejemplo tengo estos datos:

[image]

Y me interesa generar un consecutivo que se comporte de la siguiente manera:

[image]

Cabe destacar que las fechas siempre vendrán ordenadas ascendente.
No se si se pueda usar ROW_NUMBER() para esto. Espero me puedan ayudar.

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Logré solucionar el problema con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Z.DATO_ID
    ,Z.DATO1
    ,CAST(Z.FECHA AS DATE) AS FECHA
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CAST(Z.FECHA AS DATE) ORDER BY CAST(Z.FECHA AS DATE)
        ) AS CONSECUTIVO
FROM TABLA_ORIGEN Z WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY Z.FECHA ASC
```

Comment: Para optimizar en algo tu consulta, estaría demás hacer un **SET** adicional al hacer `ORDER BY Z.FECHA ASC`. Debido a que ya lo utilizas en la partición. Puedes revisar: http://rextester.com/live/OJWW33734

Comment: Muchas gracias! Le daré una revisada.